# CentOS: Mount SMB remotly

Tags: centos, smb

> **Issue & solution:** `/srv/samba` ownership was `root:root`; changing its group with `chgrp prv /srv/samba/` allowed me mount it using user
> `prv:prv` from a remote machine. Note that `/srv/samba/foo`'s
> ownership (the folder I'm trying to remotely mount) was already
> `prv:prv`, the issue came from its parent, namely `/srv/samba/`

---

First time on both CentOS and SMB, I've read several posts and guides but none of them solved my issues.

I've 2 servers (prvback & prvfront), I need to mount prvback/foo on prvfront/mnt/foo.

**PRVBACK:**

- `smbstatus -V`: `Version 3.6.23-53.el6_10`
- `/etc/samba/smb.conf` :

```
[foo]
path = /srv/samba/foo
read only = no
public = yes
domain = bar
valid users = prv
```

- `/etc/init.d/smb status`: `smbd (pid 42) is running`
- `pdbedit -L -v`

```
Unix username:        prv
NT username:
Account Flags:        [U          ]
User SID:             S-1-5-21-3498247421-334271864-1173299791-1001
Primary Group SID:    S-1-5-21-3498247421-334271864-1173299791-513
Full Name:
Home Directory:       \\prvback\prv
HomeDir Drive:
Logon Script:
Profile Path:         \\prvback\prv\profile
Domain:               PRVBACK
Account desc:
Workstations:
Munged dial:
Logon time:           0
Logoff time:          Wed, 06 Feb 2036 16:06:39 CET
Kickoff time:         Wed, 06 Feb 2036 16:06:39 CET
Password last set:    Fri, 23 Oct 2020 10:08:32 CEST
Password can change:  Fri, 23 Oct 2020 10:08:32 CEST
Password must change: never
Last bad password   : 0
Bad password count  : 0
Logon hours         : FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
```

- added 4 firewall rules

```
cat /etc/sysconfig/iptables
  -A INPUT -s 172.16.0.0/12 -m state --state NEW -p tcp --dport 139 -j ACCEPT
  -A INPUT -s 172.16.0.0/12 -m state --state NEW -p tcp --dport 445 -j ACCEPT
# [EDIT1]
  -A INPUT -s 172.16.0.0/12 -m state --state NEW -p udp --dport 137 -j ACCEPT
  -A INPUT -s 172.16.0.0/12 -m state --state NEW -p udp --dport 138 -j ACCEPT


/etc/init.d/iptables restart
```

- **[EDIT1]** configured SELinux context

```
semanage fcontext -a -t samba_share_t "/srv/samba/foo(/.*)?"
restorecon -v /srv/samba/foo/

ls -dlZ /srv/sambla/
  drwxrwxrwx.  root  root  unconfined_u:object_r:samba_share_t:s0  foo
```

- **[SOLUTION]** Change `/srv/samba` group ownership:
  `chgrp prv /srv/samba/`

**PRVFRONT**

- can connect using `smbclient`, though I've no privileges

```
smbclient //<prvback_IP>/foo -U prv
Enter prv's password:
Domain=[SDIS2] OS=[Unix] Server=[Samba 3.6.23-53.el6_10]
smb: \>
smb: \> ls
NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED listing \*
```

- can not mount remote volume

```
mount.cifs //<prvback_IP>/foo /mnt/foo -o user=prv,password=p4ssw0rd,uid=500,gid=500,domain=SDIS2

mount error(13): Permission denied
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page
```

- can't mount using `fstab` entry

```
//<prvback_IP>/foo   /mnt/foo    cifs user,uid=500,gid=500,rw,nounix,iocharset=utf8,file_mode=0550,dir_mode=0770,suid,username=prv,password=p4ssw0rd,domain=sdis2 0 0


# then
mount -a

mount error(13): Permission denied
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page
```

Does anyone has an idea about how to unstuck me ? It's a really naive question which illustrates how lost I am.

**10/26/2020 edit1 summary**

- Add context to `/srv/samba/foo` folder
- Add UDP iptables rules
- => same behavior (`smbclient` connection ok, `mount` returns error13 Permission denied)

Comment: Why are you using samba for this? Why not a network filesystem that actually supports all uniX operations line NFS?  SMB is more for Windows systems.  (Eventually Samba and the SMB protocol will support a fully posix-compliant filesystem,  it not now)

Answer (score 1):

Samba is focuses on CIFS/SMB protocol to allow connection to Windows shares on a network.  While it can be used between two linux systems, me personally I favor NFS.

For CentOS 7.x or later **selinux** can be a bbreaker.  Therefore as root on both systems do a `setenforce 0` to put selinux into permissive mode.  Any samba share folder will need the `samba_share_t` context applied to it otherwise selinux will deny it, and selinux by default is in *enforcing* mode.  You may wish to permanently put selinux into permissive mode by editing `/etc/selinux/config` and rebooting.  Do not set it to disabled.

Disable your firewall on both, by default SMB (nor NFS) is allowed.

```
systemctl disable firewalld
```

Samba requires this opened in the firewall for communication

- UDP 137
- UDP 138
- TCP 139
- TCP 445

The default firewall settings are usually in `/etc/firewalld/zones/public.xml` and only allows SSH (tcp-22) and DHCP open.

After that, if `smb.conf` has `security=user` then have an `smbpasswd -a <username>` done on *prvback* which is the samba server.  Then on *prvfront* the samba client trying to mount that smb share specify that username and password combo in the fstab.  And start with a `chmod 777 /foo` on prvback the samba server to rule out a simple folder permission issue, then chown and chmod it one step at a time while maintaining shared access.

https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Mounting_samba_shares_from_a_unix_client

Comment: You might not have noticed from the question, but it appears they are using el6 so no systemd or firewalld.

Comment: Indeed, we're not using `systemd`. I'm updating my question according to your answer